# How to add data to another class from WCF Domain Service Class methods in silverlight?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, linq

Hi i am using WCF RIA services class in Silverlight.

I do have a line chart control named `mcChart` in which i have bound the item source to `Date` and `Amount` properties of class `customer`.

```
public class Customer
    { 
      public DateTime Date{ get; set; }
      public int Amount{ get; set; }    
    }
```

I do have this method through WCF ria domain service class to access the sql table `gardenwater{Id, Date, Amt}`:

```
public IQueryable<gardenwater> GetGardenwaters()
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.gardenwaters;
        }
```

Now i want to store the data in `List<Customer> cust = new List<Customer>();` so that it can be shown in the chart.

I have tried like this :

```
EntityQuery<gardenwater> inquery = from c in wdc.GetGardenwatersQuery()
                                   select new { Date =Convert.ToDateTime(c.Date), Amount =Convert.ToInt32(c.usedwater) };
```

and then

```
foreach (var gardenWater in inquery )
            {
                cust.Add(new Customer() { Date = Convert.ToDateTime(gardenWater.Date), Amount = Convert.ToInt32(gardenWater.usedwater) });
            }

 mcChart.DataContext = cust;
```

Doing all the above i am not able to get any good results.

I want to display the data through storing SQL table data in Class properties.

Please suggest me what can i do or what mistakes i am doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it resolved by now...i can use following

```
            private ContextName context;
            private LoadOperation LoadGardenWater;
            private void GetGardenWater()
            {
                context = new ContextName();
                context.GardenWaters.Clear();
                var query = context.GetGardenWaterQuery();
                LoadGardenWater = context.Load<GardenWater>(query);
                LoadGardenWater.Completed +=new EventHandler(LoadGardenWater_Completed);
            }

            void LoadGardenWater_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                List<Customer> cust = new List<Customer>();
                if (LoadGardenWater.Entities != null || LoadGardenWater.Entities.Count()> 0)
                {
                    foreach (GardenWater item in LoadGardenWater.Entities)
                    {
                        cust.Add(new Customer()
                        {
                            Amount = Convert.ToInt32(item.Amount),
                            Date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date)
                        });
} 
}
}
```

Comment: It is fine to [accept your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it).

Comment: @GertArnold : Thanks but its showing message : "You can accept your own answer tomorrow"